# How to express symmetry of rank-2 tensor with upper and lower indices in terms of components

Tags: tensors, symmetric-matrices

In the context of general relativity, I am working with the energy-momentum tensor $T$, which is a rank-2 tensor whose components are usually denoted by $T^\mu_{\ \ \ \ \nu}$. However, I am unsure of how to write the fact that this tensor is symmetric. Which of the following two ways is correct?

$$T^\mu_{\ \ \ \ \nu}=T^\nu_{\ \ \ \mu}\ \ \ \ \ \text{or}\ \ \ \ \ T^\mu_{\ \ \ \ \nu}
=T_\nu^{\ \ \mu}$$

I am thoroughly confused by this staggered indices notation, and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you! But why? In this proof I found they seem to do it the opposite way, it's confusing. 
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/705054/preservation-of-symmetries-of-tensors-under-lowering-and-raising-indices/705059#705059

Comment: @KurtG. If it is as you say, then that means that in order to "translate" a rank-2 tensor into a matrix, the first index we encounter corresponds to the rows, and the second one to the columns? Regardless of whether they are upper or lower indices?

Comment: @KurtG. Oh, I understand, yes I can show that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KurtG. If it's not too much trouble, could you please tell me why you think the first equality is the correct one? I just got the opposite answer here, so I don't know what to believe. I get that both are equivalent if the metric (the tensor used to raise and lower indices) is symmetric, but there should be one that is correct by definition, regardless of that.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755337/how-to-express-symmetry-of-a-mixed-1-1-tensor-with-upper-and-lower-index/755338#755338

Comment: Actually: I think I was wrong! The rule is that we flip $\mu$ and $\nu$ ***and*** let them remain in their positions. $\nu$ stays a lower index and becomes the first index, and vice versa. Reading this cross post I am now totally confused. He says: the second equality is the correct one and proves the first equality.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you, that makes sense! However, as you said, both would be equivalent if the metric tensor used to raise and lower indices is symmetric. I was wondering if there is a conceptual difference, as a tensor where the first index is an upper index and the second one is a lower index must be a different mathematical object than a tensor where the opposite happens. That's why I believed the first equality would be the correct one, as you originally said. But I don't know enough about tensors to tell if this is the case or not.

Comment: @KurtG. I suspect that person who answered my other question made a mistake. The last step of their proof seems to be wrong, they wouldn't get $T^\nu_{\ \ \ \ \mu}$, but $T^\mu_{\ \ \ \nu}$. I think you were right originally, and they are wrong! But it's just a suspicion, I don't know how to prove it in a rigorous way :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abstract tensor is a machine that eats vectors and covectors and returns a scalar.
Lets consider a mixed $(1,1)$-tensor that takes a covector in its first slot and
a vector in its second slot:
$$\tag{1}
T(U^*,V)\,.
$$
When we have basis vector fields $\partial_\mu$ and $dx^\nu$ we can write this as
$$\tag{2}
T={T^\mu}_\nu\,\partial_\mu\otimes dx^\nu
$$
where ${T^\mu}_\nu$ are $T$'s components. For this tensor it does not really make sense to speak of symmetry because it does not know what to do with
$$\tag{3}
T(V,U^*)\,.
$$
How about the components  ${T^\mu}_\nu\,?$ When we have a metric tensor $g^{\mu\nu}$ that we use to raise indices and which is symmetric then, as we know,
$$\tag{4}
{T^\mu}_\nu=g^{\mu\rho}T_{\rho\nu}\,.
$$
The components $T_{\rho\nu}$ are those of a tensor
$$\tag{5}
T_{\rho\nu}\,\ dx^\rho\otimes dx^\nu
$$
that eats two vectors $V,U$ and can therefore be symmetric or not: Unlike $T(U^*,V)$ it knows what to do with the vectors when we flip them.

***Lemma.*** *If the tensor (5) is symmetric, and if $g^{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric then*
$$\tag{6}
{T^\mu}_\nu={T_\nu}^\mu\,.
$$
Proof.
$$\tag{7}
{T^\mu}_\nu=g^{\mu\rho}T_{\rho\nu}=g^{\rho\mu}T_{\nu\rho}
={T_\nu}^\mu\,.
$$
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! This is perfect. However, aren't you mixing up partial derivatives and differentials? I might be wrong here, but I think I remember from differential geometry lectures that the partial derivatives are a basis of the tangent space of a manifold, while the differentials form a basis of the cotangent space. So, if $T_{\rho\nu}$ are the components of a tensor that takes two vectors and returns a scalar, shouldn't it be $T=T_{\rho\nu}\partial_\rho\partial_\nu$? Or am I remembering this wrong?

Comment: @WildFeather I am mixing that up myself all the time and had to edit the answer around 24 minutes ago. Please consider the following: $\partial_\mu$ is a tangent vector. Therefore it is a rank one tensor that eats a covector. Perhaps they mentioned somewhere in that course that $\partial_\mu(dx^\nu)={\delta_\mu}^\nu\,?$

Comment: Ohh, of course, I'm sorry! I didn't realize that, since a tensor produces a scalar after it is evaluated at whatever combination of vectors and covectors it eats up, then a vector has to take a covector and vice versa. Thank you!